# how to pop up calendar when button is clicked in Java SWT?

Tags: swt

I am trying to develop Java SWT application in eclipse.
I need to populate text box using DateTime Calendar in SWT when a button is clicked.
I tried the following code but not able to see the Calendar, though it is created.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
        Button button;
        Label label;
        final Display dev = parent.getDisplay();        
        Image image = new Image(dev,"C:\\Users\\rm186021\\Desktop\\Calendar.gif");
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
        parent.setLayout(gridLayout);       
        label = new Label(parent, SWT.NULL);
        label.setText("Start date ");
 final Text start = new Text(parent, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
 Button calButton = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        calButton.setImage(image);
        calButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
              @Override     
              public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                final Display display = new Display();
               final Shell shell2 = new Shell(display);
               shell2.addListener(SWT.CALENDAR, new Listener() {
                 public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                 final DateTime calendar = new DateTime(shell2,SWT.CALENDAR | SWT.POP_UP);
                 calendar.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter () {
                    public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e) {
                      start.setData(" " + calendar.getYear() + "-" + (calendar.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + calendar.getDay());
                      System.out.println(start.getData());
                      //calendar.dispose();                   
                    }
                }); 
                }
                }); 
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTime` really shouldn't be created with code like that :) Try this instead:

```
calButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        final Shell shell2 = new Shell(dev.getActiveShell()); 
        // new Display() won't work on many platforms if one already exists
        final DateTime calendar = new DateTime(shell2, SWT.CALENDAR); 
        // no need to add a listener to shell2, and POP_UP doesn't work for DateTime
        calendar.addSelectionListener(...);
        shell2.open();
        // Edward Thomson noticed it wasn't called, I missed it
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You're creating a `Shell`, but never even opening it.  Try calling `shell2.open()`.
2. You're adding an `SWT.CALENDAR` listener to the `Shell`.  This isn't going to do what you want to do.  Or anything, for that matter, since `Shell` doesn't fire `SWT.CALENDAR` events.  Instead, you simply need to add the `DateTime` to a container and hook up selection listeners to the `Calendar`.
3. `SWT.POP_UP` is not an appropriate style bit for `Calendar`.

I would recommend subclassing `Dialog` (call it `CalendarDialog`, for example), setting a `FillLayout` on it, adding a `Calendar` to it and hooking up listeners that way.  Then call `CalendarDialog.open()`.